# undefined method `reviews_path' for (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, review

I am building a method in which users can review other users and I am using https://github.com/mackenziechild/movie_review as a base

views/profiles/show

```
    <%= link_to "Write a Review", new_user_review_path(@user) %>
```

views/review/._form

```
   <%= form_for([@user, @review]) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <div id="star-rating"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :comment %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

class Review < ApplicationRecord

   belongs_to :user

end


class ReviewController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

def new
    @review = Review.new
end

def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)

    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    @review.receiver_id=@user.id
    @review.save
end

private

    def set_review
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end
def review_params
```

How do I solve this?

Routes

```
user_review_index_path  POST    /users/:user_id/review(.:format)    
review#create

new_user_review_path    GET /users/:user_id/review/new(.:format)    
review#new
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :users do 

   resources :review, only: [:new, :create] 

end
```

hmm, maybe I have to do a member do?

Edit, I was playing around with it, I think it's because the model being reviewed is not being set properly in the controller

```
def set_receiver
  @review.receiver = User.find(params[:receiver_id])
end
```

Adding something like this gives me a "no resource found" error

How do I set the receiver of the review since it's another user?

Comment: show the route and detailed exception log.

Comment: how do I get the detailed exception log?

Comment: hello, please add you `routes.rb` file

Comment: I just added routes.rb